# Dynamic Programming in a Grid - Why create the table Top-Down?

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I was doing this question on Codechef 
http://www.codechef.com/PRVG2015/problems/PRVG154/

The summary of the problem is that Alex starts from the top left corner, wishing to maximise the total score, and Bob wishes to minimise the total score by subtracting the elements coming in his way.
They move alternatively, and they can pick only the elements which are either to the right or to the bottom of the previously selected element. 
While forming the table, it can be seen that if (i+j)%2==0 then that element can only be picked by Alex, and otherwise, it can only be picked by Bob. 
So for (i+j)%2==1, we change A[i][j] to -A[i][j], so that later on, we only have to add elements, minimising or maximising depending on the index.

All the solutions I have seen seem to create the DP[n][m] table in a top down manner, going from bottom right corner to the top left corner (Reverse order)(i.e. from dp[n-1][m-1] to dp[0][0]). Why is this done? 
I have tried going from top left corner to bottom right corner too, but it doesn't give the correct solution, though the logic appears fine.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);

int t, n, m, A[500][500],i,j;
int dp[500][500];

cin>>t;

while(t--)
{
    cin>>m>>n;

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            cin>>A[i][j];

    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((i+j)%2 == 1)
                A[i][j] = -1 * A[i][j];
        }
    }

    dp[0][0] = A[0][0];

    for(i=1;i<m;i++)
        dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + A[i][0];

    for(j=1;j<n;j++)
        dp[0][j] = dp[0][j-1] + A[0][j];

    for(i=1;i<m;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((i+j)%2 == 0)
            {
                dp[i][j] = max(dp[i-1][j],dp[i][j-1]) + A[i][j];
            }
            else
            {
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1]) + A[i][j];
            }

        }
    }


    cout<<dp[m-1][n-1]<<"\n";

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: dynamic programming really is the saving of intermediate results only. the way you store them is secondary. In most cases it's just a matter of style (but I didn't have a thorough look into your code as I have to leave my desk).

Comment: This case might actually be different because there are two players involved, one wanting to maximise and the other minimise. Please give it a look when you're free

Comment: try change `(i+j)%2 == 0` to `(i+j)%2 != 0`

Comment: No it didn't work. I still get different answers from the correct reverse approach.

Comment: 1
3 4
1 3 7 4
6 4 2 5
8 9 1 4

This should give -9

Comment: Your solution will not give correct answer because at each step you are either maximizing or minimizing. But it may occur that at a particular minimizing step you should choose maximum one because both option of opponent is worse than any of previous choice. Lets say you have option (3, 5) and this is minimizing step, you would select 3 obviously. But then 3 gave opponent option of (8, 4) but if you would have selected 5 it would have given opponent option (4, 2). In previous case ans would be 12 but in later it would be 9. So basically you are doing greedy & not DP.

Comment: **it would be 11(3+8) & 9(5+4).

Comment: Oh. Okay. This explains my mistake. Can you tell why the reverse approach works though?

Comment: need code....reverse approach also should not work..may be something is different in those codes.

Comment: http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/5925948